# What would the government of a medieval city be like if it were transported through time and space?

Tags: medieval, politics

I'm working on a story where an advanced civilisation show up near a medieval city (probably the capital) but there's an issue with their ship and through tech-wizard shenanigans the warp system transports the entire city on a new world, where they are cut off from the rest of the kingdom.

Knowing that the political system was an elective monarchy like that of the HRE (although a coup was in process) but no army is there to enforce the power.

Would a city of about 30,000 people suddenly think up democracy, would they turn to the few nobles that remain or would some kind of new system arise? Maybe an authoritarian one like seen in a lot of post-apocalyptic stories?

Comment: Not clear who is transported where. Is medieval city transported to a modern world? We have plenty of developing nations to see that. City is mostly about culture, that will have the grearest effect

Comment: Funny idea to answer, but I have to VTC, more details are needed.. because now, *any* answer would do. Without knowing anything about the "new world" target planet, the answerer could just invent some target planet and weave a story around your city being transported to it. There's no best answer and we can't just write your story for you. Tip: tell a bit more about the target planet where your city is transported to, I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: What exact large medieval city you have in mind which had any use for noblemen in its government? (30,000 inhabitants is a *large* medieval city.) How does the city obtain its sustenance in the new world, so that the inhabitants don't die of starvation? You do of course realize that they had an entirely different idea of what "democracy" meant; no, nobody in their right mind even considered that one person one vote would be a reasonable system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very little would change.

Assuming you transported the farmland and satellite towns as well not much would change, the modern state did not really exist. The local ruler had more sway than any distant ruler. no outside ruler was really needed.

If you didn't bring the farmland and satellite town the city will starve within a week.